# Condition check for matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $A= \begin{bmatrix}2a & 2b \\ 2c & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=2\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, then how is $A=2B$ ?

Also, how is this possible?
$\begin{vmatrix}B\end{vmatrix}=2^2\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}$
 If $A =kB$ then $\begin{vmatrix}A\end{vmatrix}=k^n\begin{vmatrix}B\end{vmatrix}$, where $n$ is the order of determinant $A$.

Ps. [ ] denotes matrix, | | denotes determinant.

Comment: Sorry! Now the question is fully edited

Comment: Answer if you can! 

Comment: As "fully edited" it isn't true that $A=2B$, you have $A=B$.

Comment: @almagest That is what I was wondering!

Answer (score 0):

First, note that for a random matrix with coefficients in a field $\Bbb K$ (typically $\Bbb R$), the scalar multiplication with an element of $\Bbb K$ is a definition. There is no proof.

Let $A \in \Bbb K^{m \times n}$. Let's write $a_{i, j} \in \Bbb K$ the coefficient of the $i$-th row, $j$-th column of $A$. Then we define $kA$, $k \in \Bbb K$, to be the matrix such that the coefficient of the $i$-th row, $j$-th column of $kA$ is $k \cdot a_{i, j}$.

And one can define the determinant using Leibniz formula :

Let $A \in \Bbb K^{n \times n}$, where $\Bbb K$ denotes a field. Then the determinant of $A$, $\det(A)$ is :
$$\det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^na_{i, \sigma(i)} $$

Then it follows that $\det(kA) = k^n\det(A)$ :
$$\det(kA) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^nka_{i, \sigma(i)} =  \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) k^n \prod_{i=1}^na_{i, \sigma(i)} = k^n \left( \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^na_{i, \sigma(i)} \right) = k^n \det(A).$$

Comment: Sorry this is higher level.

Comment: Can someone else answer this?

Answer (score 0):

As Desura pointed out, the scalar multiplication is just a matter of definition. If $A$ is a general $m \times n$-matrix and $k$ is a real number, then $kA$ is the matrix where **all** elements of $A$ are multiplied by $k$. From this definition, it is clear that $A=2B$ in your example.

For the determinant, you may have seen that the determinant is linear in all the columns and the rows. This means (for columns):
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a+u & b \\
c+v & d
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}
u & b \\
v & d
\end{vmatrix}$$
The same holds for the second column and in general, for $n \times n$-determinants.

Secondly, because of this linearity, you also have the property:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
ka & b \\
kc & d
\end{vmatrix} = k\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}$$
The same holds for the second column and in general, for $n \times n$-determinants (and, as I said before, for rows as well). Repeating this last property, yields:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\color{blue}{k}a & kb \\
\color{blue}{k}c & kd
\end{vmatrix} = \color{blue}{k}\begin{vmatrix}
a & \color{red}{k}b \\
c & \color{red}{k}d
\end{vmatrix}= \color{blue}{k}\color{red}{k}\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}= \color{green}{k^2}\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}$$
You can easily see how this generalizes to the $n \times n$ case, extracting a factor $\color{green}{k^n}$ when you consider an $n \times n$-matrix $kA$.